# Using XSLT 2.0 to replace unknown number of strings

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

We have user-editable XML configuration files for our software, which is then unmarshalled in our Java application. We want to allow us or our users be able to add new variables to be used in strings within the configuration file.

I have XML with this structure:

```
<root>
    <variables>
        <key1>foo</key1>
        <key2>bar</key1>
        ...
        <keyn>nthbar</keyn>
    </variables>

    <some-tag>PlainText.${key1}.${keyn}.${key2}.MorePlainText</some-tag>
    <other-tag>${key3}</other-tag>
</root>
```

I'm aware that I can use XSLT 2.0 to do something like this to replace the values for known keys:

```
<xsl:variable name="key1" select="root/variables/key1/text()" />
<xsl:variable name="key2" select="root/variables/key1/text()" />
...
<xsl:variable name="keyn" select="root/variables/key1/text()" />

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace( replace( replace( ., '\$\{val1\}', $key1), '\$\{val2\}', $key2), '\$\{valn\}', $keyn)" />
</xsl:template>
```

The trouble is that this isn't very flexible. A new replace() needs to wrap the existing replace() calls every time a new key is added, and a new variable would need to be declared in the corresponding xsl file.

Is there a slick way using XSLT to refer to tags like value by using something like ${keyn} in a string elsewhere in an XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a key to match your `variables/*` elements and you can use `analyze-string` to find the `{$var}` in text nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="variables" match="variables/*" use="local-name()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | * | comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/variables"/>

    <xsl:param name="variable-pattern" as="xs:string">\$\{(\w+)\}</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$variable-pattern}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('variables', regex-group(1), $main-root)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I guess it would be better to raise an error if a match is found but `key('variables', regex-group(1), $main-root)` does not find any definition:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$variable-pattern}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="var-match" select="key('variables', regex-group(1), $main-root)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$var-match">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$var-match"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:message select="concat('No match found for $', regex-group(1))"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>           
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you! The only changes I had to make were to rename root to my actual root tag, and to make sure the <variables> tag contents was copied over to the output - I'll be needing those ;-)

Comment: Note that this isn't quite equivalent to the original code. In the original, if replacing `${key1}` produced a string containing `${key2}`, then further replacements would occur on that key. In @MartinHonnen's solution the output of a replacement is not considered for further substitution.